# vector::emplace_back for objects with a private constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I want my Timer objects to be created via Timer::create() only. For this purpose, I made the constructor private. However, I get a compiler error saying that "Timer::Timer(unsigned int)' is private" within the context of new_allocator.h. How can I solve this problem?

```
class Timer {
    private:
        int timeLeft;
        Timer(unsigned int ms) : timeLeft(ms) {}

    public:
        static std::vector<Timer> instances;
        static void create(unsigned int ms) {
            instances.emplace_back(ms);
        }
};

std::vector<Timer> Timer::instances;
```

Comment: Of course, the only reason why `push_back` would work is because the copy/move constructor is public. If all constructors are private, neither `emplace_back` nor `push_back` will or can work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably should implement your own allocator, that will be friend to timer:

```
class Timer {

    struct TimerAllocator: std::allocator<Timer>
    {
        template< class U, class... Args >
        void construct( U* p, Args&&... args )
        {
            ::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        template< class U > struct rebind { typedef TimerAllocator other; };

    };
    friend class TimerAllocator;

    private:
        int timeLeft;

    Timer(unsigned int ms) : timeLeft(ms) 
    {}

    public:
        static std::vector<Timer, TimerAllocator> instances;
        static void create(unsigned int ms) {
            instances.emplace_back(ms);
        }
};

std::vector<Timer, Timer::TimerAllocator> Timer::instances;

int main()

{
    Timer::create(100);
}
```

The simplest solution would be derive from `std::allocator<Timer>` reimplementing `rebind` to rebind to itself, so `vector` couldn't rebind allocator back to `std::allocator` and implement own `construct` to actually create `Timer`s.

Comment: … or you can make `std::vector<Timer>` a `friend` of your class. Not quite as clean but much simpler.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, that's not so simple: Of course, I'd advice to make vector friend, if it works, but the thing is that vector _does not call constructor, allocator does_. Making vector friend will not help.

Comment: Ah, true of course. I just recommended this in another answer where it *worked* (with a `std::deque`) but now I’m not sure *why* it actually works.

Comment: Thanks, this works well for my purpose (even though I don't quite understand allocators and templates yet).

Comment: Why not simply `friend class std::allocator<Timer>;`?

Comment: @leemes, because there is no guaranty, that `std::allocator<Timer>` will create Timer _itself_ and will not be rebinded (or will not delegate construction) to some other allocator. Actually, in my `gcc 4.7.0` is _does_ get rebinded, so making it frined doesn't help also.

Comment: Why not make all of `std::allocator<T>` a friend? That way, rebinds won't matter.

Comment: @NicolBolas, how are you going to do that? Also, what if allocaltor will be rebinded to some internal type (like how it actually goes with my compiler)?

Comment: @Lol4t0: "*how are you going to do that?*" Like this: `template<typename T> friend class std::allocator<T>;`. Thus every instantiation, even with some internal type, is a friend.

Comment: @NicolBolas, that doesn't seem to be correct syntax, and then it would not make `template<typename T> __gnu_internal::__some__allocator<T>` Timer's friend.

Comment: @Lol4t0: Then your std::allocator implementation is not conforming. The C++11 spec requires std::allocator<T>::construct to have the effect of calling placement new. Thus, it isn't allowed to forward that call to someone else.

Comment: @NicolBolas, the effect of calling placement new is not the exactly calling placement new. If it could only call placement new, what would be the point of allocator. Anyway, its my mingw standard library behavior and I have to live with that. Of course I first tried simpler solutions, but this is the simplest that works for me.

Comment: @Lol4t0: "*If it could only call placement new, what would be the point of allocator.*" The *custom* allocator you use can do whatever it wants. But the *actual* `std::allocator` default will call placement new. That's what the standard *requires*.

Comment: @Lol4t0: I specifically said to use [`friend template<typename T> class std::allocator<T>;`](http://ideone.com/dmwhsj). And the fact that it fails [due to an obvious non-conforming implementation](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/QyFpkqNGStk) doesn't change the fact that it *ought to work*. I'm arguing in accord with the *standard*, not a broken implementation.

Answer (score 15):

You can use transfer-of-friendship semantics to avoid having to have a specialized `vector` allocator. It's a bit like dependency injection of friendship. This is really quite simple. You create an empty class who makes itself a friend of your class. But the default constructor is private, so only your class can create instances of it. But the class is still copyable, so it can be passed to anybody.

Your `Timer` constructor will be public, but it requires one of these objects as an argument. Therefore, only your class, or a function called by it, can create these objects directly (copies/moves will still work).

Here's how you could do that in your code ([live example](http://ideone.com/LzK7e1)):

```
class TimerFriend
{
public:
  TimerFriend(const TimerFriend&) = default;
  TimerFriend& operator =(const TimerFriend&) = default;

private:
  TimerFriend() {}

  friend class Timer;
}

class Timer {
    private:
        int timeLeft;

    public:
        Timer(unsigned int ms, const TimerFriend&) : timeLeft(ms) {}

        static std::vector<Timer> instances;
        static void create(unsigned int ms) {
            instances.emplace_back(ms, TimerFriend());
        }
};

std::vector<Timer> Timer::instances;
```

Comment: Here is [more compact version](https://gist.github.com/valmat/69c67f94daf75452e2ae987aa67d55be) of `TimerFriend` (`private_key`) and `Timer` ctor.

Comment: @arcadius: Note that the user can still get access [by doing this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xhnevE53o). This can't happen in my version (in C++20 at least) because the default constructor of the friend type is explicitly private.