# Copy constructors for classes with mutual referencing/cyclic dependecies

Tags: c++, c++11

So I have what I think is a pretty common C++ problem involving object
composition. The problem domain is this: an animated gif can have many
frames, and drawing a frame depends on the context of the Gif's other
frames.

So I have this model (much simplified for this question, but should
illustrate):

```
class Gif {
  std::vector<Frame> _frames;

  // Makes Frame objects from file and puts them in _frames
  Gif(const char* file){...};

  // For clarity, works and copies the _frames member
  Gif(const Gif& other) = default;
};

class Frame {
  Frame(...){
    // Make a frame object
  }
  void draw(const Gif& context){
    // draws self considering context's other frames
  }
};
```

This works, but for simplicity sake and to avoid drawing a `Frame` in
the wrong context, I wish the `draw` method would not take that `context` argument. So I thought of creating Frames with a `const`
reference member `_context`:

```
class Frame {
  const Gif& _context;

  // Make a frame object
  Frame(const Gif& context) _context(context){...}

  // Explicit default copy-constructor, for clarity. Breaks horribly
  // when called from Gif's copy constructor, since the new Frame will
  // reference the wrong context, which might be deleted.
  Frame(const& Frame other) = default;


  void draw(){
    // draws self considering _context's other frames
  }
};
```

This compiles but breaks horribly when copying `Gif`s. The `Frame`
objects of the new `Gif` are copies alright, but they reference the
wrong context, which has typically been deleted already.

I take it that const reference members are probably a bad idea for
objects that you intend to copy... Should I use a pointer and
explicitly reset it for the new `Frame`s in the body of a custom `Gif`'s copy constructor?

If so, what kind
of pointer (raw/smart)? Isn't there a good C++11 technique for making
this happen "automatically"?

Or should I be breaking the cyclic dependency and how?

EDIT (thanks to KillianDS): To be clear, you start from gif1 with some frames (frame1_1, frame1_2, ...) that point to gif1 and now you want to copy gif1 to gif2 with copied frames (frame2_1, frame2_2,...) but that point to gif2?

Comment: To be clear, you start from `gif1` with some frames (`frame1_1, frame1_2, ...`) that point to `gif1` and now you want to copy `gif1` to `gif2` with copied frames (`frame2_1, frame2_2,...`) but that point to `gif2`?

Comment: yes @KillianDS, exactly

Comment: It seems users of the `Gif` class can access object (references) of the `Frame` class. Why not make `Gif` instead publish some kind of pointer type `FramePointer` that contains `Gif const* context` and `Frame* frame`?

Comment: @dyp and could this new object be copied? What if it is and then the `Gif` and the `Frame` dissapear? If it isn't copiable maybe the idea works yes, can you make it into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I thought a little bit more about this and came to this working example.
This is actually the second version, the first used `unique_ptr`'s and `push_back`. This version uses `emplace_back` and perfect forwarding per @KillianDS's suggestion. To forbid creation of new Frames without going through `Gif::add_frame` also uses a `FrameFriend` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007977/vectoremplace-back-for-objects-with-a-private-constructor).

```
class Gif;
class FrameFriend {
  friend class Gif;
private:
  FrameFriend(){}
};

class Frame {
public:
  int _number;
  const Gif& _context;

  // Constructors are public but a FrameFriend is needed and only Gif
  // can make one. And frames can't be copied or copy-assigned.
  Frame(int number, const Gif& gif, const FrameFriend&) : _number(number),_context(gif) {}
  Frame(Frame&& other) = default;
  Frame operator=(Frame other) = delete;
  Frame(const Frame& another) = delete;

  // ... but they can be constructed from ther frames
  Frame(const Frame& another, const Gif& gif, const FrameFriend&)
    : _number(another._number),
      _context(gif) {}

  void draw(){}
};


class Gif {
  // Each gif owns its frames exclusively
  std::vector<Frame> _frames;

  // Privately, frames can be copied from other gifs
  // calling the appropriate private constructor of Frame
  void copy_frames(const Gif& other){
    _frames.clear();
    _frames.reserve(other._frames.size());
    for (auto& f: other._frames) {
      _frames.emplace_back(f, *this, FrameFriend());
    }
  }

public:
  // Public constructors
  Gif(){};
  // Public constructors. Copying and assigning both call
  // copy_frames() which updates the the gif context
  Gif(const Gif& other) { copy_frames(other); }
  Gif& operator=(Gif& other) { copy_frames(other); return *this;}
  // Move constructor can be the default
  Gif(Gif&& other) = default;

  // Add a frame
  void add_frame(){
    _frames.emplace_back(_frames.size(), *this, FrameFriend());
  }

  // The set of frames can be publicly accessed and frames can even be modified
  // individually, but as no 
  std::vector<Frame>& frames() { return _frames; };
};
```

Comment: You don't actually need any pointers here anymore, just work with regular variables and maybe use [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to speed up things. I'd also use [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) in the copy code to avoid unnecessary allocations.

Comment: @KillianDS: what do you mean I don't need pointers? `emplace_back` and `reserve` sound like good ideas.

Comment: @KillianDS I figured it out. Thanks! The process turned out exactly how I originally requested it, and `emplace_back` and perfect forwarding look exactly like the C++11 idiom that I was looking for. I can accept your answer, but perhaps you can edit to mention that this idiom is clearly better.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to let the copied frames point to the copied gif. This won't work with a default copy constructor on both levels as you don't blindly copy the objects. Your `Gif` copy constructor likely needs to become something like this:

```
class Gif {
  std::vector<Frame> _frames;

  Gif(const Gif& other) : some_var(other.some_var), _frames(other.frames) ... 
  {
      for(auto& frame: _frames)
      {
          frame.update_context(this);
      }
  }
};
```

Now the problem is that in the Frame class you're using references, which cannot be reseated, so you can't update them. If your use case is simple as this usually you can get away with a naked pointer:

```
class Frame {
    const Gif* _context;

    // Make a frame object
    Frame(const Gif* context) _context(context){...}

    Frame(const& Frame other) = default;
    void update_context(const Gif* context) { _context = context; }
};
```

Why a naked pointer and not a smart pointer:

1. There is no reason for a Frame to do memory management on Gifs, it is just a reference.
2. It seems unlikely you'll ever have frames without a Gif context. But even in this case and a frame starts without a gif, you can just use `std::nullptr`.
3. You want to avoid smart pointers, because your frames point to your gifs who 'point' to your frames who point to ...

When should you think making this a smart pointer (`std::weak_ptr` in this case) is if point 2 is no longer correct. If a frame starts with a gif and the gif gets lost somewhere, but the frame doesn't, it's easier to use a `weak_ptr` where you can actually check if the gif context is still there. With naked pointers you should always put the pointer to `nullptr` otherwise and this is more error prone.

Comment: I think this works yes. as for point 2. Not only is it unlikely it is highly undesirable. If possible I want the compiler to forbid me from making this mistake.  I now believe that Frame itself should be made uncopiable and the vector should be a vector of unique_ptr's to it.

Comment: See my answer: I prefer it as it avoids the naked pointer and is safer overall, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @JoaoTavora that is of course also a good solution but results in a very different API, where Frames are not seperately constructible, this was not an original requirement.

Comment: true. I discovered the "right" API as I went along. I don't think there's a way to make them separately constructible without making it easy to violate the model's integrity, i.e. end up with a `Frame` that references a `Gif`, but that `Gif` does not reference it back, or vice versa.