# Create a std::vector of type having private constructor

Tags: c++11, stdvector, allocator

I have a class whose constructors are private. I need to create a std::vector of instances of this class. Now, I am providing my own allocator for this purpose and the class has the allocator as a friend. However on MSVS 2015 with C++11, I get the error as:

```
error C2664: 'const MyClass*std::_Wrap_alloc<MyClass::MyClassAllocator>::address(const MyClass&) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::_Container_proxy' to 'MyClass&'
```

Here is my allocator:

```
struct MyClassAllocator: std::allocator<MyClass>
{
    template <class U, class... Args>
    void construct(U* ptr, Args&&... args)
    {
        ::new(reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptr)) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <class U> struct rebind { typedef MyClassAllocator other; };
};
```

This allocator is taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17008204/2648754).

Edit:

Here is a MVCE which produces the error in MSVC 2015 with update 3.

```
#include <vector>

class MyClass
{
    friend struct MyClassAllocator;

public:
    ~MyClass() {}

private:
    MyClass() {}
};

struct MyClassAllocator: std::allocator<MyClass>
{
    template <class U, class... Args>
    void construct(U* ptr, Args&&... args)
    {
        ::new(reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptr)) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <class U> struct rebind { typedef MyClassAllocator other; };
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<MyClass, MyClassAllocator> vector;
    vector.emplace_back();
}
```

The error that is produced is:

```
tests.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(591): error C2664: 'const MyClass *std::_Wrap_alloc<MyClassAllocator>::address(const MyClass &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::_Container_proxy' to 'MyClass &'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(586): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::_Vector_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<_Ty,_Alloc>>::_Free_proxy(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=MyClass,
1>              _Alloc=MyClassAllocator
1>          ]
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(559): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Vector_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<_Ty,_Alloc>>::_Free_proxy(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=MyClass,
1>              _Alloc=MyClassAllocator
1>          ]
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(680): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Vector_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<_Ty,_Alloc>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=MyClass,
1>              _Alloc=MyClassAllocator
1>          ]
1>  src\tests.cpp(157): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<MyClass,MyClassAllocator>' being compiled
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the error. With only this much information it is hard to help you.

Comment: MSVC implementation rebinds to an allocator for `_Container_proxy` class (some internal class; not sure what it's used for). But your `rebind<U>::other` doesn't in fact produce an allocator capable of allocating objects of type `U`. I'm pretty sure this violates allocator requirements.

Comment: Ah. It's for [iterator debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/debug-iterator-support). In debug built, `vector` implementation allocates additional data structures to keep track of outstanding iterators, to be able to warn of iterator misuse (e.g. use after invalidation). It uses the container's allocator to allocate those structures, by way of `rebind`. Perhaps if you disable iterator debugging, the program will compile. Though it still exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed due to iterator debug levels.